# Can we have a callback after each in cypress?

Tags: cypress

```
cy.get(someselector).each(($el) => {
 cy.wrap($el).invoke('text').then((text) => {
   if(text){} else {}
   // Do something
 });
});
cy.get(someselector).click(); // this is getting called before each block executes
```

Can we do something after each block executed only. Tried with waitUntil, was not successful. Later moved cy.get(someselector).click();  to different test itself to get rid off this issue.

But is there a way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have asked, it is highly unlikely -

> // this is getting called before each block executes

This is because Cypress uses a **queue system** and the commands like `.each()` and `.click()` must happen **in the order they are placed in the queue**, which is the order you place them in the test.

It is possible some construct inside the body of `.each()` callback causes some delay in execution that fools the queue system. That is why Cypress performs sometimes checks that result in message -

> "Error: you returned a promise within a command".

But you have not shown the full codes, so it is not possible to diagnose that for you.

Well, I can say this - add another layer of callback, sort of manual queue system:

```js
cy.get(someselector).each(($el) => {

})
.then(() => {
  cy.get(someselector).click()
})
```

But is unlikely to help you since I think you misdiagnose the problem from the start.

---

By the way, your handling of text is not good either. You should attempt to keep all code within the `.each()` callback synchronous if possible (meaning do not use un-needed `.wrap()` command).

```js
const text = $el.text()
if (text !== '') {
```